# What type of switch is this push switch [photos]?

Tags: switches, identification

I suspect this switch isn’t functioning correctly and would like to replace it but can’t find one similar. What sort of switch is it?

The front is a push with two states (in/out) and has a bulb to indicate on/off (though that’s not currently working). It’s probably from early 90s or late 80s.

[image][image][image]

This is a similar switch that I got a better photo of, though it has extra wires out. The switch of interest is in the background.

[image]

Comment: The [RS] logo is the central hint here: rs-online.com

Comment: @MarcusMüller yup, no part number though. I have had a look at rs-online but couldn’t see a match, hoping someone else with more knowledge of what they’re searching for may have more luck.

Comment: I have found similar looking ones such as [this](https://uk.rs-online.com/mobile/p/push-button-switches/1739335/) but there are several that look identical that have different descriptions.

Comment: It looks like it may be energizing a relay through the bulb.  I could see doing that if it were essential to safety to only energize a circuit when the bulb was lit -- running a relay coil through the bulb would insure that a burnt-out bulb de-energized the relay.  If that's the case, then replace the bulb and you'll be back in business.

Answer (score 2):

The diagram on the side is pretty clear -- the top terminals are for a bulb, the "middle" (one up from the bottom) terminals are a NC contact, and the bottom terminals are a NO contact.  It's almost, but not quite, a SPDT switch -- it's more like a DPDT switch that's missing some terminals.

**BUT** looking at the picture, it's running current from the contacts through the bulb.  It may be that the burnt-out bulb is an essential part of the circuit (possibly for safety reasons, to never energize a circuit unless there's an indicator light).

Dig through the rs-online site; this should be pretty obvious.

If all you need is a replacement, and looks don't matter, then by the diagram and the wiring, only the NC section (and possibly the bulb) is being used -- so you just need a normally-closed (or closed-when-out) SPST push-push switch with a bulb.

Answer (score 0):

It’s either a momentary or toggle push-push latching switch .   What makes you think it is not Functional?

They do make cheaper ones too. https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/push-button-switches/0319449/

Comment: It’s latching rather than momentary. The continuity didn’t seem right, might be because we didn’t realise the type of switch.

Comment: How does it feel?